# How to override classes in the Java API, thus changing their behaviour using Reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, overriding, code-injection

Is it possible to override the Exceptions class and thus inject my own methods into it, thereby changing it's overall behaviour. I believe I read somewhere that it could be done using custom class loaders or some reflection technique? I think it mentioned using a custom class loader to load your custom class rather than loading the default Java API class. If so how might one do this, for instance creating a JOptionPane exception message popup upon calling printStackTrace(e) that alerts the user to the exception message.

Comment: Why not just write a method `public static void showErrorDialog(Throwable)`? There's code which depends on `printStackTrace` doing something in particular. It's not a good idea to go and make it do something completely different. That's why it's not allowed in the first place.

Comment: @Radiodef My interest was in printing to screen alerts when uncaught exceptions were thrown, because unless you have the console running in the background, the user may remain completely unaware that one has been thrown which could lead to unexpected behaviour. showErrorDialog(Throwable) would only allow me to determine when an exception has been thrown that i am already aware of and am handling it in a trycatch statment, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: What you should actually do in that case is use a [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-). Also see http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Yeah thats fair, cheers

Comment: It was slightly different to the XY problem because i was also interested in whether Y was possible in the first place if nothing else but out of curiosity, therefore in reality i wanted to know the answer for both and was told that Y was the means to accomplish X by a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in packages starting with `java` are protected by the JVM itself, so in order to be able to change classes in these packages, you need much more than just a different class loader. Instead of going this way, you might just set your own PrintStream using `System.setErr` that is opening the alert box showing text that is printed there. This then not only includes calls of `printStackTrace` but everything that is printed on STDERR. You might use some filtering by checking the calling stacktrace of a freshly created Exception if the call comes from a `Throwable` or other classes that you want to support and ignore the rest.

Comment: Cheers, I didn't consider that